# Anaconda installation error: unable to add conda to PATH

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

### Problem

I had been using Anaconda as my python package manager until yesterday when I accidentally interrupted the `conda update conda` command. Ever since I am not able to use the `conda` command -- it gives command not found error.

### What I've tried:

I tried re-installing the Anaconda package(without adding it to the PATH during installation). It still **wouldn't recognize the conda command**. Also, the **anaconda navigator doesn't open**.

I uninstalled the package and re-installed it, this time checking the 'Add to PATH' checkbox. This is what I'm getting.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: It is a permission error, try installing as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

When the PATH variable does not contain the location of your Anaconda installation, the windows console (cmd.exe) does not know where to look for the "conda" command.

You should start the installation with "Run as Administrator" so the installation script can change your PATH variable.

Alternatively you could install like before and add the correct location to the PATH variable yourself. (Type "Environment Variable" in Windows search)